# Why didn't Joi sync properly with Mariette?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

In *Blade Runner 2049*, after Officer K retires from LAPD, he arrives at his home. Joi synchronizes her holographic program with Mariette, so she is able to control Mariette's body.

[image]

We can still see the faces of both Joi and Mariette. Why didn't Joi sync properly with her?

Comment: Not sure Joi can synchronise perfectly (and no one in the film says that this kind of sync is possible).  They both seem to be doing their best to hack a solution to the physical contact deficit that Joi units suffer from.

Comment: I always interpreted it as Joi being a sort of "skin" over Mariette so Joi and K could feel like they were interacting with one another.

Comment: I do not remember the actual dialogue from the scene but she was trying to mimic and anticipate her movements as much as possible. I believe that she even requests her to not move so quickly initially so that she can (what I assume to be) build a better profile of her movement style and help her program to more easily anticipate her movements. Given that Mariette was a human being it would be impossible for Joi to perfectly sync with her. If I get a chance to rewatch and copy the dialogue before someone else does I will post it below.

Comment: She didn't control, she performed movements so that joi could get in sync with Mariette. Then whenever Mariette moved while "doing the horizontal tango" she could perform similar movements to keep the illusion that joi was physical

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It was their first time and not an easy thing to do

Joi had never done this 'sync' thing before, neither had Mariette. It's not something that is easy, even for an advanced holographic device such as Joi.

There's one thing to clear up though, Joi was in no way controlling Mariette's body. It was that Joi was 'synced' to Mariette's movements, to provide the illusion that it was in fact *her* interacting with K, and not Mariette.

Comment: I wonder if syncing here is not time or motion related since movements would be unpredictable but rather the term means simply that she needed to adjust her dimensions to those of the replicant.

Answer (score 1):

Joi could not completely sync with Mariette. Being a hologram, and with the aspect of Mariette perpetually moving, even ever slightly slow, Joi would provide a slight mask over her, but would always be a delayed tracing, or lagged following Mariette. Think of it like a shadow that has to consciously follow you and must process your movements perfectly, but cannot predict what the body will do next.

Comment: This sounds like a good answer, however can you provide any evidence for your claims?

Comment: I'm going off of the fact that Joi is using motion sensor technology that relies on a camera that is housed in a house, combined with the quotes she says to Mariette, something akin to "Slow down so I can sync properly." Admittedly, it is more based upon technology we have today mixed with the element of scifi

Comment: But if Joi believes she can sync properly, why was she unable to?

Comment: I think what we were shown was the extent of Joi syncing up properly. At the greatest power she had.

Comment: Fair enough. Either way, might be worth seeing if you can find that quote and add it into your answer.

Comment: Good point, lemme go and try to find the clip.